# mouseover event is not fired up to click event fire in d3

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, d3.js

I am new for **d3**, I worked on **tree** chart, on that **mouseover** event is not fired up to **click** event fire. If the **click** event is fired on some node the **mouseover** is worked only for those child nodes only.

code is :

```
 var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
  .attr('pointer-events', 'all')
  .on("mouseover", overNode)
  .on("mouseout", outNode)
  .on("mouseUp",mouseUp)
  .on("click", click);

function click(d) {  
   if (d.children) {
      d._children = d.children;
      d.children = null;  
   } else {
      d.children = d._children;
      d._children = null;  
   }  
   update(d);
}
```

Comment: probably due to you appending 'g'. This is a grouping element, it isn't anything other than a way to group multiple elements. Also, .attr('pointer-events ... should be .style('pointer-events ....

Comment: @thisOneGuy even pointer-events removed also not working. How can I go forward?

Comment: Can you see your nodes ? Remove the append('g')

Comment: Even if i add the listeners to the circle and is also not worked out. 
` nodeEnter.append("circle")
   .attr("r", 1e-6)
   .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });`

Comment: put the mouseevents, i.e mouseover, mouseout, mouseup and click after you append the circle. Should be fine then

Comment: @thatOneGuy No it is also not working, even if we append the text and circle also.

Comment: can you show more code or create a jsfiddle

Comment: @thatOneGuy can you check it once.. [js fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/xdpzrxx1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/thatoneguy/xdpzrxx1/2/

This is working. I have added the following to test :

```
    .on("mouseover", function(d){ console.log(d); overNode(d)})
    .on("mouseout",  function(d){ console.log(d); outNode(d)}) 
    .on("mouseUp",  function(d){ console.log(d); mouseUp(d)})
    .on("click",  function(d){ console.log(d); click(d)});
```

I have also moved your DragDropManager object to the top of the JavaScript as before it wasn't getting found. This was due to it being global and instantiated after other elements, that depended on it, were created.